# where is function read for boost socket

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I want to read certain amount of bytes in my application using boost socket. I heard that onc there was read function to do it, but now it's missing. Does anybody knows how can I handle it? Is there an asynchronous way to do it especially?

Comment: Of interest: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/bsd_sockets.html

Comment: Also, examine/borrow from the examples: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

You want [`boost::asio::async_read()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html). It can read a specific number of bytes, pay attention to the numerous overloads however.